# Backbone listening to collection sync event in my View

Tags: backbone.js

Can some advise what the best approach is for listening for the `sync` event on my collection. Should it be `on` or `listenTo`, kind of confused by what's right.

```
this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);

// or

this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
```

Comment: It's explained in the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)

Comment: Hey, yeah I'm aware of the docs; confused as which one I should use though. Should I just use listenTo all the time since it handles cleaning itself up instead of having to manage `on` and the `off`?

Comment: Yes, use `listenTo` unless you want to manage the cleaning manually. I suppose if for some reason you want to re-use listeners then `on` or `off` is the way to go but I can't really think of any real life situation where `listenTo` won't be a better choice.

Comment: Do note that it's not automagic, you or the library need to call [stopListening](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) which Backbone will do in a view's [remove](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove).